# How to scale app so iPhone 6 is identical(zoomed) to iPhone 5 SpriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, resize, scaling

Ive been making an app using sprite kit in Xcode 7. I made all my sprite nodes positioned around by referencing other sprite nodes and self.frame
 for example

```
self.block.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)
```

When I came to test my app on an iPhone 6 Plus (I previously tested on iPhone 4s but it worked nicely on an iPhone 5) My app didn't scale the nodes, Just the space Between them. The game relies on everything being the same otherwise people playing on an iPhone 6 would find it easier then people playing on a smaller device. Is there anyway that I could make the iPhone 6 view just a stretched version of the iPhone 5 view? Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0):

It's best not to position your sprites using self.frame as a reference. Much better to treat the scene as the "true" coordinates and let SpriteKit scale your scene for you.

ie. Specify the scale mode of your scene when you create it (probably in the view controller viewDidLoad). I prefer AspectFill for the scale mode,  which makes sure the screen is filled, but you will lose the edges on some devices. Just make sure the core gameplay is in the middle of the scene.

```
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
```

Then, position your sprites using the size of your scene for reference. On a landscape scene, I tend to use a scene size of 1024x768 (iPad size).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another way: If you remove the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ launch images from the project then those devices will switch to "zoom mode", which is exactly the same view as on iPhone 5, just bigger (well, zoomed).

Just look in your project for "Images.xcassets", there is a image-set called "LaunchImage". In this image-set are multiple other images, just remove the one for iPhone 6 and 6+.

Comment: How do I do this. I am quite new to IOS development!